# ¿como hacer que el combobox cambie con un texto que traigo de un textfield?

Tags: java

tengo un inconveniente, tengo un combobox que tiene tiene estos ítems

1. SELECCIONAR
   TECNICO LABORAL EN AUILIAR DE ENFERMERIA
   TECNICO LABORAL AUXILIAR EN SALUD ORAL
   TECNICO LABORAL EN SERVICIOS FARMACEUTICOS
   TECNICO LABORAL DE SEGURIDAD EN EL TRABAJO
   TECNICO LABORAL EN ACOMPAÑANTE DOMICILIARIO
   TECNICO LABORAL EN COSMETOLOGIA Y ESTETICA INTEGRAL

al seleccionar uno de ellos este se va a un txtfield así:

```
    private void cbProgramaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String programa = cbPrograma.getSelectedItem().toString();
    txtProCurso.setText(programa);
    
}
```

luego guardo ese dato en la BD, también ahí van incluidos otros datos pero eso no les pongan cuidado, solo el que dice programa

```
          String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("INSERT INTO inscritos (ID,fecha,ciudad,programa,JorDiurna,JorNocturna,primerApell,segundoApell,nombres,fechaNaci,lugarNacimi,eps,ars,cualAseguradora,nivelSisben,otroSisben,docuCC,docuTi,docuOtro,NumDocume,Expedida,generoM,generoF,edad,tipoSangre,estadoCivilSoltero,estadoCivilCasada,estadoCivilUnionL,estadoCivilOtro,ocupacion,correoElec,direccionReside,telefono,barrio,estrato,entidadTrabaja,cargo,fechaIngresoEm,direccionEmpre,telefonoEmpre,nombreAcudiente,cedulaAcudiente,fechaNaciAcudiente,telefonoAcudiente,parentesco,profesionAcudiente,secundariaInstitu,secundariaCiudad,secundariaTitulo,secundariaAno,tecnicoInstitucion,tecnicoCiudad,tecnicoTitulo,tecnicoAno,univeInstitucion,univeCiudad,univeTitulo,univeAno,CulturaIndigena,culturaAfro,culturaReinser,culturaRoom,culturaCabezaF,culturaFrontera,culturaDezpla,pagoCredito,pagoContado,matriculado,inscrito) "
     + "VALUES (null, '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", oPersonas.getFecha(), oPersonas.getCiudad(), oPersonas.getPrograma(), oPersonas.getJorDiurna(), oPersonas.getJorNocturna(), oPersonas.getPrimerApell(), oPersonas.getSegundoApell(), oPersonas.getNombres(), oPersonas.getFechaNaci(), oPersonas.getLugarNacimi(), oPersonas.getEps(), oPersonas.getArs(), oPersonas.getCualAseguradora(), oPersonas.getNivelSisben(), oPersonas.getOtroSisben(), oPersonas.getDocuCC(), oPersonas.getDocuTi(), oPersonas.getDocuOtro(), oPersonas.getNumDocume(), oPersonas.getExpedida(), oPersonas.getGeneroM(), oPersonas.getGeneroF(), oPersonas.getEdad(), oPersonas.getTipoSangre(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilSoltero(), oPersonas.getEstadiCivilCasada(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilUnionL(), oPersonas.getEstadoCivilOtro(), oPersonas.getOcupacion(), oPersonas.getCorreoElec(), oPersonas.getDireccionReside(), oPersonas.getTelefono(), oPersonas.getBarrio(), oPersonas.getEstrato(), oPersonas.getEntidadTrabaja(), oPersonas.getCargo(), oPersonas.getFechaIngresoEm(), oPersonas.getDireccionEmpre(), oPersonas.getTelefonoEmpre(), oPersonas.getNombreAcudiente(), oPersonas.getCedulaAcudiente(), oPersonas.getFechaNaciAcudiente(), oPersonas.getTelefonoAcudiente(), oPersonas.getParentesco(), oPersonas.getProfesionAcudiente(), oPersonas.getSecundariaInstitu(), oPersonas.getSecundariaCiudad(), oPersonas.getSecundariaTitulo(), oPersonas.getSecundariaAno(), oPersonas.getTecnicoInstitucion(), oPersonas.getTecnicoCiudad(), oPersonas.getTecnicoTitulo(), oPersonas.getTecnicoAño(), oPersonas.getUniveInstitucion(), oPersonas.getUniveCiudad(), oPersonas.getUniveTitulo(), oPersonas.getUniveAno(), oPersonas.getCulturalIndigena(), oPersonas.getCulturaAfro(), oPersonas.getCulturaReinser(), oPersonas.getCulturaRoom(), oPersonas.getCulturaCabezaF(), oPersonas.getCulturaFrontera(), oPersonas.getCulturaDezpla(), oPersonas.getPagoCredito(), oPersonas.getPagoContado(),oPersonas.getMatriculado(), oPersonas.getInscrito());
     objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
```

tengo una tabla la cual me muestra los usuarios que he guardado, al seleccionar en el usuario me trae los datos incluyendo el del programa, este dato lo trae a la textfield

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces al traer los datos de la BD me trae el nombre del programa a ese txtfield pero por lógica el combo box no cambia al item con ese nombre, y eso es lo que quiero,
agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: Cuando seleccionas un registro en el JTable, lo pega en automático en el TextField, no?

Comment: si, cuando presiono el registro lo lleva